# jruby, glassfish gem and bundler

Tags: glassfish, jruby, bundler

I wonder if anybody has the following issue:

in a jruby environment, I can do:

```
gem install glassfish
```

no problem

But if I add

```
gem 'glassfish'
```

to my Gemfile and do

```
bundle install
```

it always complain glass fish gem cannot be found.

Any solution to this? Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turned out to be something wrong with the Gemfile.lock. deleted the file and reinstall fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `source "http://rubygems.org"` in your Gemfile? I just tested

> ```
>  source "http://rubygems.org"
>  gem 'glassfish'
> ```

and it was fine:

> ```
> $ cat > Gemfile
> source 'http://rubygems.org'
> gem "glassfish"
> $ jruby -S bundle install
> Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
> Using rack (1.3.5) 
> Installing glassfish (1.0.3) 
> Using bundler (1.0.21) 
> Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
> ```

Having said that, please keep in mind that glassfish gem is not maintained at this time. For the alternatives, please check this blog post: http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2011/taking-stock-jruby-web-servers/

Comment: Actually if I started freshly like you did, it worked. Just not working when I added it in a existing Gemfile. weird. I will investigate more

Comment: didn't notice the "not maintained" part. trying trinidad. thanks